# How to keep the image and card in the same proportion of size in react bootstrap?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have a card inside a vertically aligned card groups:

[image]

The react code:

```js
import React from 'react';

import { Container, CardGroup, Card, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

const styles = {
  card: {
    backgroundColor: '#B7E0F2',
    borderRadius: 55,
    padding: '3rem'
  },
  cardImage: {
    objectFit: 'cover',
    borderRadius: 55
  }
}

export default function FindingsPage() {
  return(
    <Container fluid>
      <CardGroup className="m-5 d-block">
        <Card className="m-5 border-0 shadow" style={styles.card}>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <Card.Img src={require("../assets/images/findingsPage/EnglishesOfTheWorld.jpg")} style={styles.cardImage} />
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title as="h1">Englishes of the World</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text as="h4" style={styles.cardText}>
                How do your grammar intuitions depend on when and where you learned English? Participants took a short grammar quiz, which we are using to understand how grammar differs in different parts of the English-speaking world (USA, Ireland, Australia, etc.). We are also investigating how grammar is different for people who learn English later in life: Do they make different mistakes if their first language is German as opposed to Japanese?
              </Card.Text>
              </Card.Body>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Card>
      </CardGroup>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

However, when the text length is longer than the image height, the image doesn't stretch:

[image]

I was wondering is there a way to fix that? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure about the stretch part? you might wanna make it center, otherwise, stretching will make it our of proportion.

Comment: @MuhammadKamran Yes, but like zoom in a little bit, keeping the same ratio, so the image will not be distorted.

Comment: Well, you are using cover prop in style so it should be doing that, but it is possible that <Col> is not giving it space so try inspecting and check how much space is available and tweak accordingly, if you have code in github then I'll help.

Comment: @MuhammadKamran I want the image to be on the left half of the card, text on the right half of the card. So I added the <Col>. Here is the repo: https://github.com/hrcn/pushkin-sitetemplates-default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured that out, just add `height: '100%'` to the `cardImage` in styles.

Answer (score 3):

Good! However, if you want to have more performant images then you should consider the following width & height values:

```
100px
33vw
20em
calc(50vw-10px)
```

In other words:

```
cardImage: {
objectFit: 'cover',
borderRadius: 55,
width: '50vw',
height: '30vh'
}
```

Here is a reference for more information: https://web.dev/serve-responsive-images/